# JHipster me avisa cuando ejecuto mvn en Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, jhipster

Hola a todos y gracias por esta increíble herramienta (tanto JHipster como StackOverflow):
Estoy usando una versión de Linux Mint, y cuando ejecuto mvn recibo el siguiente aviso:

"npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"}) "

Quiere eso decir que JHipster prefiere que se usen ordenadores Apple? Todo funciona con normalidad, pero ese mensaje me ha extrañado un poco.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. El idioma oficial del sitio es el Español, asi que debes [edit] tu pregunta para traducirla.

Comment: Nno te olvides de modificar el titulo tambien!!!  y no, no pasa nada.. el error dice que para esa dependencia se necesita otro OS, que es distinto al tuyo.. en general yo la recibo en todos mis proyectos porque trabajo con windows...

Comment: Si sigues el enlace de la pregunta que marco como duplicada, tienes una excelente respuesta de @PabloLozano